# Font Awesome icon inside of HTML input with Angular working

Tags: html, angularjs, font-awesome

I am trying to make this, but not having much luck:

```
<input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-show="ppt.Globals.hasDebitCard" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 2 ? -1 : 2)"  value="outstanding swipes"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" ng-show="ppt.Swipes != null"></i></input>
```

Problem didnt exist until I knew I need the icon, but being HTML compliant, I cannot make this work that great. Tried switching the button input type to an anchor with the same logic, but a no go. Ideas please?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Button instead of Input as below

```
<button class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-show="ppt.Globals.hasDebitCard" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 2 ? -1 : 2)"  value="outstanding swipes"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" ng-show="ppt.Swipes != null"></i></button>
```

With Input you are limited to text whereas Button can have chilren like img or i

Answer (score 1):

Use `Button` will work!

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-show="ppt.Globals.hasDebitCard" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 2 ? -1 : 2)"  >outstanding swipes <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" ng-show="ppt.Swipes != null"></i></button>

<br/> 
<span>More examples with link, from font awesome site:</span> <br/>

<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings</a>

<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i> Delete</a>
```